# Find next element in array, if latest go first

Tags: javascript, arrays

How I can get the next element in the array, but, if is the latest then go to the first available in the Array.

```
[1,2,3,4,5].find(3) => 4
[1,2,3,4,5].find(5) => 1
  [1,2,4,5].find(3) => 4
  [1,2,4,5].find(0) => 1
```

Comment: Seems pretty basic. What have you tried?

Comment: Wouldn't the third example be `find 3 => 5`?

Comment: @Feathercrown no, because is looking for the value 3 and uses the next available

Comment: @j08691 I've tried: ``  var closest = counts.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
   return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? prev : next );
  });``

Comment: @greenbandit Then why does the third example return 3? Are you extrapolating that there should be one there? What if your array isn't linear like that?

Comment: @Feathercrown third example is looking for 3 in value, since is not there takes the next close to 3 which is 4

Comment: So if the array was [1,5,4,2] what would it return?

Comment: @Feathercrown, It is supposed to be an ordered array, and depends on the number you're looking for, if you're looking for `2` it should returns `1` because is latest and need point to the first one, if you find for `3` should return `4`

Comment: @greenbandit I think you need to better clarify the conditions of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Seems simple enough with just a simple loop:

```js
console.log('[1,2,3,4,5].find(3) =>', findNumber([1,2,3,4,5], 3));
console.log('[1,2,3,4,5].find(5) =>', findNumber([1,2,3,4,5], 5));
console.log('[1,2,4,5].find(3) =>', findNumber([1,2,4,5], 3));
console.log(  '[1,2,4,5].find(0) =>',  findNumber([1,2,4,5], 0));


function findNumber(array, numberToFind) {
  for (var i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
    if (array[i] > numberToFind) {
        return array[i];
    }
  }
  return array[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create function that first checks if number is in array and if it is it returns next element else use `while` loop to increment to next number and return it.

```js
function findNumber(ar, num) {
  var i = ar.indexOf(num);

  if (i != -1) {
    return (i != ar.length - 1) ? ar[i + 1] : ar[0];
  } else {
    while (true) {
      if (num > Math.max.apply(null, ar) || num < Math.min.apply(null, ar)) return ar[0];
      if (ar.indexOf(num) != -1) {
        return num;
      } else {
        num++
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(findNumber([1, 2, 3, 4], 2))
console.log(findNumber([1, 2, 4, 5], 3))
console.log(findNumber([1, 2, 5], 6))
console.log(findNumber([1, 2, 5], 0))
```